# Google Cloud Functions returning 401 error after thousands of correct responses

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I'm writing a genetic algorithm that uses a Cloud Function as its evaluation function and have been running into 401 response codes about 1/3 of the way into the process.  I'm not entirely certain what is going on here given the numerous successful invocations, and there are no indications in the Google Cloud logs that anything is amiss (either in the CF logs or the generic cloud-wide logs).

The intention is to use it as a generic evaluation function for more 'rigorous' projects, however for this one I am passing a list of strings, along with the 'correct' string, and returning the ASCII distance between each string to the correct string.  This information is coming in as a JSON packet.  The genetic algorithm basically just needs to discover the correct string for completion.  This is basically a play on the `one-max` optimization problem.

For reference, this has only really happened once I scaled up the number of invocations and passed strings.  The process ran fine with a smaller number of evaluations and amount of strings passed, however when I scale it up a bit it chokes halfway through).  Note that the entire purpose of using CFs is to try and scale exponentially upwards for evaluation calls, otherwise I'd just run this locally.

The Cloud Function is fairly trivial (evaluating the string optimization problem):

```
import json

# Evaluate distance from expected to individual
def fitness(bitstring, expected, dna_size):
  f = 0
  for c in range(dna_size):
    f += abs(ord(bitstring[c]) - ord(expected[c]))
  return f
    
def evaluateBitstrings(request):
  resp = []
  request_json = request.get_json()
  if request_json and 'bitstrings' in request_json and 'expected' in request_json and 'dna_size' in request_json:
    for bitstring in request_json['bitstrings']:
      f = fitness(bitstring, request_json['expected'], int(request_json['dna_size']))
      resp.append((bitstring, f))

    return str(json.dumps(resp))
  else:
    return f'Error: missing JSON information'
```

The JSON packet I'm sending comprises a list of 1000 strings, so it's really just doing a loop over those and creating a JSON packet of distances to return.

It is configured to use 512mb of memory, has a 180 second timeout, and uses authentication to protect from anonymous calls.  I trigger the call locally via Python, `asyncio`, and `aiohttp` with the authorization included in the header (authenticating locally in Windows Subsystem for Linux (Ubuntu) via `gcloud`).

Here is the relevant bit of Python code (using 3.6).  One of the issues was being locally-bound with the large number of `aiohttp` calls, and I came across this [post on using semaphores to increase the amount of calls used with semaphores](https://pawelmhm.github.io/asyncio/python/aiohttp/2016/04/22/asyncio-aiohttp.html).

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
...
base_url = "https://<GCF:CF>"
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
...
token = sys.argv[2] # call to `gcloud auth print-identity-token` as parameter
headers['Authorization'] = 'bearer ' + token

async def fetch(bitstrings,expected,session):
  b = {'bitstrings':bitstrings,
       'expected':expected,
       'dna_size':len(expected)}
  async with session.post(base_url, data=json.dumps(b), headers=headers) as response:
    assert response.status == 200
    data = await response.read()
    try:
      return json.loads(data)
    except:
      print("An error occurred: {0}".format(data))

async def bound_fetch(sem, bitstrings, expected, session):
  async with sem:
    return await fetch(bitstrings, expected, session)

async def run(iterable, expected, token):
  tasks = []
  sem = asyncio.Semaphore(1000)

  async with aiohttp.ClientSession(trust_env=True) as session:
    chunks = [iterable[x:x+1000] for x in range(0,len(population), 1000)]

    # build up JSON array
    for chunk in chunks:
      task = asyncio.ensure_future(bound_fetch(sem, chunk, expected, session))
      tasks.append(task)

...

# Within the GA code
for generation in range(ga.GENERATIONS):
  ...
  loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
  future = asyncio.ensure_future(run(population, ga.OPTIMAL, token))
  responses = []
  results = loop.run_until_complete(future)
  for res in results: # loop through task results
    for r in res: # json coming in as a list
      responses.append((r[0], float(r[1]))) # string, fitness
```

Further reference, I have done this locally via the `functions-framework` and did not run into this issue.  It only happens when I reach out to the cloud.

---

Edit: I resolved the Forbidden issue (the token needed to be refreshed, and I simply fired off a subprocess call to the relevant `gcloud` command), however now I am seeing a new issue:

`aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host us-central1-cloud-function-<CF>:443 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('216.239.36.54', 443)]`

This now happens sporadically (10 minutes in, 70 minutes in, etc.).  I'm starting to wonder if I'm fighting a losing battle here.

Comment: Is it take time before getting the first 401 return code? Or from the first request the issue occur?

Comment: It runs for about a half hour successfully and then returns 401

Comment: In reviewing my runs, seems to die at an hour.  I wonder if its possible that my login token needs to be refreshed somehow

Comment: It's my exact assumption. The token expire and thus you are forbidden.

Comment: I resolved the token issue, but seem to be getting a new issue.  I updated my question.